# Filter data table in php

Tags: php

I have a php web app that filters data between date range, but when i select date from two date time picker, it doesn't display, below is script and please tell me what am i missing?

By the way '$post_at" and '$post_at_to_date' are my variables to 2 date time picker:

$post_at = "FROM Date"

$post_at_to_date = "To Date"

```
  <?php

  if(isset($_POST['search']))
  {
    $post_at = $_POST['post_at'];
    $post_at_to_date =  $_POST['post_at_to_date'];
    $cmbDept = $_POST["search"];
    $query ="SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE Checkdate BETWEEN '$post_at' and '$post_at_to_date' ";
    $search_result = filter($query);
   }
   else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2";
    $search_result = filter($query);
   }
   function filter($query)
   {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","bio_db");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
   }                
 ?>
```

And this is my action code:

```
  <form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="index.php">
 <p class="search_input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="post_at" name="post_at"  value="<?php echo $post_at; ?>" class="input-control" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="To Date" id="post_at_to_date" name="post_at_to_date" style="margin-left:10px"  value="<?php echo $post_at_to_date; ?>" class="input-control"  />             
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Search" >
</p>
```

For Fill table

```
  <table align="center" width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Userid</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Campaign</th>
            <th>Checkdate</th>
            <th>Hoursworked</th>
            <th>Overtime</th>
        </tr>

    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Userid'];?></td>
            <td width="200"><?php echo $row['Name'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Campaign'];?></td>
            <td width="100" style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Checkdate'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Hoursworked'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Overtime'];?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php endwhile;?>

        </table>
```

SCRIPT for mysql which display and filter my data.

```
       SELECT * FROM `daily_data2` WHERE Checkdate BETWEEN '2016-03-01' and '2016-03-31'
```

Comment: `$post_at` and `$post_at_to_date` are initialized to empty string, but not filled with values from `$_POST['search']` ? `$post_at = $_POST['search']['post_at']` before filter call

Comment: what should it be? I tried to this if(isset($_POST['search']['post_at']['post_at_to_date'])) but nothing happens

Comment: `if( isset($_POST['search']['post_at']) && isset($_POST['search']['post_at_to_date']))`

Comment: still the same, nothing happens when i clicked search button

Answer (score 1):

Missing

```
$post_at = $_POST["search"]['post_at'];
$post_at_to_date = $_POST["search"]['post_at_to_date'];
```

Full version

```
<?php

  $post_at = "";
  $post_at_to_date = "";

  if(isset($_POST['search'])
 &&  isset($_POST['search']['post_at'])
 &&  isset($_POST['search']['post_at_to_date'])
 ) {
 $post_at = $_POST["search"]['post_at'];
 $post_at_to_date = $_POST["search"]['post_at_to_date'];

    $query ="SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE Checkdate BETWEEN '".$post_at."' and '".$post_at_to_date."' ";
    $search_result = filter($query);
   }
   else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2";
    $search_result = filter($query);
   }
   function filter($query)
   {
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","bio_db");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
   }
```

Comment: still it doesn't do the filtering